# run docker commands with linux "at" function

Tags: linux, docker

I am running a PySpark script that runs a while loop for 2 hours. I'd love to be able to schedule this to run overnight.

I type in these two lines in order to run the code. After ssh into the server I type:

```
docker exec -it r-hadoop-spark-yarn-spark-master-1-085ae410 bash
```

This takes me to a working directory in Docker, I then type:

```
nohup /opt/spark-2.0.2/bin/spark-submit --master spark://hadoop-spark-yarn-spark-master-1:7077 --executor-memory 8G bm_plog_hdfs.py &> SparkPLOG.out &
```

to run the script (if all goes well).

I have tried inserting these two lines, without the 'bash' into a script and scheduling this with 'at' but it doesn't appear to run.

Comment: remove the `-t`, and I believe it'll work - at jobs run without a terminal, and the `-t` option is asking to connect the terminal up.

Answer (score 0):

Try the dettached mode using `-d` by running:

```
  docker exec -d r-hadoop-spark-yarn-spark-master-1-085ae410 bash -c "nohup /opt/spark-2.0.2/bin/spark-submit --master spark://hadoop-spark-yarn-spark-master-1:7077 --executor-memory 8G bm_plog_hdfs.py &> SparkPLOG.out &"
```